# Accessing Django's context when testing with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: django, testing, selenium

I want to use Selenium in my Django tests, but I can't find a way to access Django's context, like you can do with [Django's default test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/).

For example, using the test client, I can see if forms have errors and what template is being used:

```
response = self.client.get('/')
self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
self.assertEqual(resp.context['form']['code'].errors, [u'This field is required.'])
```

How do I do this if I'm using the Selenium WebDriver?

```
driver = self.driver
driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
# ???
```

The only hint of a solution I have been able to find is the possibility that [the Django test client can be extended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#customizing-the-test-client). Could you somehow swap it out with the Selenium WebDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helpful context stuff is stripped out by the time something like Selenium gets the response.

You could write a simple middleware class to add this back in, though. Something like:

```
class AddContextMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
         response['debug_stuff'] = str(response.context_data)
         return response
```

Then your response object will have a header, "debug_stuff", with the context_data that Django normally offers to middleware. You could examine that in Selenium.

**Important**: DON'T DO THIS ON PRODUCTION. There's quite-possibly sensitive stuff in that context_data you don't want the world being able to pry into.

This seems like a useful enough thing to do that I wouldn't be surprised if someone has already created a Django add-on for it. You might check around the usual django package sites.

Comment: Well, that's clever and I guess it could be made to work, but I was kind of hoping for something a little cleaner. (Note that perhaps it would be better to [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) the context or something. It seems like converting it to string could be problematic.)

Comment: +1 @joelburton I prefer your answer.  I was thinking in the way of context from objects not of context from html responses.  Testing different stuff of coarse.  Yea, i think travis was referring to html responses.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example.  You would use the `assertIn` method:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver 


class SeleniumViewTests(LiveServerTestCase):

# load fixtures
fixtures = ['product_data.json', 'admin.json']

def setUp(self):
    self.browser = WebDriver()

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()


def test_news_article(self):

    # Get the News Article in question
    article = NewsArticle.objects.all()[0]
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
    body = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
    self.assertIn(article.title, body.text)
```

[edit] Just a note, here you are just calling: `get(self.live_server_url)` so it will call your index page, or LocalHost:8000 for example if your testing on your Local machine

[edit] You can just call the object for the content that you are trying to test.  Then test if the context is in the content of the response using `assertIn`.  At least that is how I've done it.

Comment: (I'm not sure this answer the original question, though, which is more about how to get the Django *context*, not the rendered *content* of the response)

Comment: you've edited it to compare a Django object to an element of the rendered HTML (which is a useful thing). But it's not actually checking the Django *context data*--if you don't know, when you use the Django internal test client, it adds the actual raw (i.e., not rendered in HTML) view context_data to the response as a special object. That's what gets stripped out before external test clients (or real browsers!) get to it.

Comment: Arguably, having a "functional test" using something like Selenium cheat and use internal-only data structures, rather than rendered HTML, is a questionable idea. But there are times when it can be a useful hack.

Comment: If I search the HTML for a form error message, it could match the same error coming from a different form field, or it could match help text saying "If you get error X, then see page Y for more details." I could probably use CSS selectors to narrow my search, but then the back-end processes become dependent on (front-end) CSS selectors staying the same. I think that accessing Django's context is the only reliable way to be sure the correct form element is throwing the correct error.